# Platform Encryption want to encrypt manged Objec's Field

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, platform-encryption

Well we have a managed packaged installed , WE did necessary setup required for encryption. Now I can able to encrypt custom fields out side the manage package but , system do not display where to change that the Fields is encrypted.

I am looking for two Questions

1. Can we apply encryption to managed Packaged Fields ?
2. If Not where I can specify that this fields is encrypted ? Is there any way to specify in source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_security_pe_packages.htm

> When you install a managed package in your Salesforce org with Shield Platform Encryption, you can encrypt custom fields in the package. You can encrypt any field that belongs to one of the encryptable custom field types.
>
> **Engage your app vendor to make sure they are prepared to support encrypted custom fields in their package. Then contact Salesforce support to enable this capability for your org.**
>
> As an admin, this may increase the range of packages you can leverage, because more packages will be encryption-ready out of the box. (Not all of them, though! Check with the app vendor that a package is compatible with encryption before you install it.)

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_custom_fields.htm&type=5

> You can encrypt the contents of fields that belong to one these custom field types, on either standard or custom objects.
>
> - Email
> - Phone
> - Text
> - Text Area
> - Text Area (Long)
> - URL
> - Date
> - Date/Time

**HOWEVER**

It looks like the app has to support it and you need to contact SF support to enable it (See above):

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/ISVPlatformEncryption#Six_steps_process_to_adapt_your_package_to_Shield_Platform_Encryption

Comment: As per you first statement it is clear that  you can encrypt custom fields in the package. And I Agree 100%. My question is Can we enable encryption for the non custom fields which is provided by package ?

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_security_pe_packages.htm

Comment: Salesforce allow to add encryption on the managed package fields but it says If you’re an app vendor, talk to Salesforce support about getting set up to support customers who encrypt custom fields used by your package Did any one tried to Do it ?